# Instalación magento 2 con nginx y centos 7

Tags: nginx, permisos, centos, magento2

Hola estoy en el proceso de instalación de magento2 en un servidor con S.O Centos7 y servidor Nginx para la instalación segui el tutorial

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-magento-2-1-on-centos-7/

La instalación termina de forma correcta pero al iniciar la url del home me muestra errores en los permisos de lectura y escritura como muestro en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el /var/log/nginx/error.log de nginx muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la estructura del proyecto tiene los siguientes permisos y el usuario nginx

Carpeta principal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido de la carpeta var done dice que tengo problemas de permiso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para dar los permisos use el comando

```
chmod 777 var/*
```

asignar un usuario a la carpeta deseada para los permisos

```
chown -R nginx:nginx luma_1
```

Configuracion de nginx

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para php-fpm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

configuracion para magento2

/etc/nginx/conf.d/magento.conf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Daniel, agrega a tu pregunta (usa este enlace: __[edit]__) la líneas adecuadas de tus archivos de configuración de nginx, de tu sitio y de fpm  para verificar que esté correcto. Especialmente, es importante conocer el usuario que ejecuta los procesos de PHP.

Comment: el usuario que debte tener acceso a la carpeta es www-data, intenta hacer `sudo chown -r www-data:www-data /vaar/www/nginnx/html `